# How to open a child shell in a new tab in bash so that I have a parent and a child shell running simultaneously?

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to study the about shells and I was exploring about how variables are shared among child and parent shells. I am able to open a child shell in the same tab as the parent shell. However, at this time, I am not being able to make changes in the variables in the parent shell since the child shell is running. So I needed to open the child shell in a new tab instead, so that I can work on both the child and parent shells simultaneously. Is this even possible?

Comment: From the perspective of the shell, there's no such thing as a "tab".  This is a question about your terminal emulator.

Comment: There's not much to study, though. The child receives a copy of the parent's environment when it starts; after that, they are separate.

Comment: @SupreethBaliga : You have to use a Terminal program which allows you to do this. If you find one which offers this feature, let us know.

Answer (score 0):

You can stop the child shell then tell it to run in the background with "bg". The echo $$ command returns the shells pid, and the kill -19 sends the stop signal to the pid.

```
$ echo $$
19863
$ kill -19 19863
[1]+  Stopped                 sh
$ bg
[1]+ sh &
$
```

After you've made your changes to the parent shell environment variables you can "fg" to foreground the child shell.

You can also look into "screen" and "xterm &" these are 2 other ways to launch a sub shell and easily interact with the parent shell.